# Ansible use if condition at hosts

Tags: ansible, devops, hosts

I am trying to pass a variable called 'ci=hostname' from Ansible cmdline and what I am looking for is it should pick that variable 'if defined' but if not, then it should pick 'pod_Cluster_cl'. I tried it but it gives out an error that 'ci' is NOT defined variable.

I think I need to use some other conditional rather than using "!=" but don't know which. Something equivalent to

> "ifdef"

maybe?

```yaml
---
- hosts: >-
    {{ ci
      if ci != 0
          else 'pod_Cluster_cl'
    }}
```

Comment: For this trial to work, you need the [`defined` test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-tests.defined): `if ci is defined`. The `default` filter shown in the answer is probably more convenient, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `default` filter.

```yaml
---
 - hosts: "{{ ci | default('pod_Cluster_cl') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting one error. 
`- hosts: {{ ci | default:'pod_SE_Cluster_cl' }}`
It complaining about the "**:**" just after default.We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes

Comment: @fm2ahmed You are right. The quotes were missing.

Comment: I tried using quotes around the curly brackets But now it gives this error. `ERROR! template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'. String: {{ ci | default:'pod_SE_Cluster_cl' }}`

Comment: Just to let you know that **pod** & **cl** are two variables that I pass through cmdline as well. Ex. -e `"pod=RDG1 cl=4"`

Comment: `- hosts: "{{ ci | default('pod_Cluster_cl') }}"`, rather.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε If I use the above it doesn't give me any syntax error BUT as I am passing two variables via Ansible cmdline i.e. **pod=RDG1** and **cl=4** and that should translate to **RDG1_Cluster_4** but it doesn't work in my case. I get this error as the those 2 variables are not translated to the expected values. `[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: pod_Cluster_cl

PLAY [pod_Cluster_cl] *****
skipping: no hosts matched`

Comment: **That** was totally **not** clear from your question.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I got it working at-last. Using this sorted out getting the variables translated - `- hosts: "{{ ci | default(pod + '_SE_Cluster_' + cl) }}"` I got this reference from [link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9867)

Comment: Well, since `cl=4`, you'd be better of with `- hosts: "{{ ci | default(pod ~ '_SE_Cluster_' ~ cl) }}"`, as `~` is the concatenation operator, not `+`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Yeah, but the answer I got initially got me to my 2nd question. But good that your suggestion helped me as well. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: This question has been answered and can be closed. I tried to vote for it but can't as my rank is 11, need 15 to vote.